# Why does my "pm2 logs" process continue running after my ssh connection closes?

Tags: node.js, bash, ssh, pm2

I have a bash script I use for accessing the pm2 logs on my server:

```bash
ssh user@hostname source ./activate-node-env.sh && pm2 logs my-app
```

It works great -- the log stream opens up (as though I'm running `tail -f`), and I ctrl-C when I'm done.

But recently I noticed that a bunch of `pm2 logs` processes were running on the machine:

```
ps ax | grep node
 1509 ?        Ssl    8:18 node /root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/bin/pm2 logs my-app --lines 20
 4133 ?        Ssl    0:34 node /root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/bin/pm2 logs my-app --lines 20
 5369 ?        Ssl    8:15 node /root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/bin/pm2 logs my-app --lines 20
 7466 ?        Ssl    8:21 node /root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/bin/pm2 logs my-app --lines 20
 8408 ?        Ssl   19:37 node /root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/bin/pm2 logs my-app --lines 20
```

It seems that when I ctrl-C out of my ssh session, the pm2 logs process never exits.

What's going on here? How do I make sure my processes are cleaned up when I ctrl-C?

Answer (score -1):

Pm2 basically allows any application to run on background. As long as the system is running, pm2 will make the application run on background. So, even if you exit the ssh, as the system is still on & working, pm2 will also run the application in background and gives you the output log.

Comment: I appreciate your try, but I don't think you understood my question. I am asking specifically about running the `pm2 logs` command over ssh, not about using pm2 as a process manager.